# How we can play private Youtube videos in android using password?

Tags: android, youtube

I want to play **private** Youtube video on my android device, does anyone know about it?

URL:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1fuuhECPSI&feature=g-upl&context=G2a4cbe5AUAAAAAAAAAA

How we can pass parameter in youtube url ,like username and password?

Thanks

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

Before you start the intent to view the video.. [Create a dialogbox with textinput to get the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061249/opening-a-dialog-with-text-input-from-within-a-view-in-android).
use sharedpreferences to save your password.. and check it with the password entered... if it matches.. then start the intent..